# Is there any way to use CSS3 properties in older browser (JS?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, border-radius, box-shadow, etc...

I am looking for something that would work on IE6+

Comment: why you need to do this?

Comment: because he lives in the last millenium! always be nice to timetravelers!

Comment: because CLIENT lives in the last millenium! FTFY ;-) Serious answer: My client uses IE6 at work and cries because it doesn't look as good on at work than on his laptop!

Comment: Oh, so he would rather have it load four times slower? http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-IDPlE0Mjg0c/TuEic4JWyeI/AAAAAAAAAJo/Ir5Vb_FMILg/s1600/wile+e+coyote.jpg

Comment: btw.. supporting IE6 just makes people that use it keep using it which is a bad thing for every web developer :D

Comment: I know... but at the same time, what do you want me to do? The client is always right (?!?!?).. I did try to educate him on that matter... But he's really stubborn...

Comment: @GungFoo Unfortunately it is still infeasible to (for corporate stuff) entirely ignore IE7 (not to mention IE8, which is also a dinosaur) .. which has/have enough issues .. just far less.

Comment: Ppl please stop telling developers to stop supporting iex for x < current. There is a huge bunch of us who do not have a choice. For example a huge org running XP cannot upgrade to IE9 and may be stuck on XP for logistical reasons. Just upgraded from fx 3.6 to 10 where I live. Yes we all want to code for chrome 27+ only and I would like a toilet seat of solid gold but that is just not in the cards, baby.

Comment: supporting any version of internet exploder should be considered a form of madness.

Comment: Netscape Navigator 1.1, anyone?

Comment: @GungFoo Corporations run older versions of IE. This will not change, sadly. The Microsoft antiquation process takes awhile and corporate IT is not about being "cutting edge". It is about being. And yes, IE7 is still *very* prevalent.

Comment: Corporations by their very nature behave like sociopaths.. http://www.sociopathworld.com/2009/09/is-corporation-sociopath-writ-large.html

Comment: @mplungjan Supporting it means making sure the website is functional. Not doing the craziest things to try to make it look and behave *exactly* like a browser that's ten years younger.

Comment: @Ana you would be surprised how long I had to support IE6 with look and feel and not just function.

Comment: @mplungjan No, you didn't have to. You chose to. You can try to explain to people that trying to emulate the look & feel in IE6 is like taking a 90 year old man out of his wheelchair and forcing him run a marathon. And if they don't understand, you can tell them they cannot count on you for such a job. This *is* a choice. It can cost you money, it can cost you a job, but it is a choice.

Comment: Now you are just being silly. Meet you in the real world. Anyway, they got it in the end. Now we are stuck on ie8 for another couple of years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/). It allows you to add most of the CSS3 functionality in Internet Exploder.

Comment: The two others suggested selectivizr.. Why should I pick CSS3PIE? Any advantage (other than the name, obviously!!!)? (I don't know any of those)

Comment: selectivizr = 6-8. pie claims it is 6-9. (since 9 is still missing alot)

Comment: Selectivzr merely lets you use CSS3 style *selectors* (hence the name). CSS3PIE allows for the user of CSS3 *properties* through .htc files.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by  [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) (A useful JavaScript tool for implementing CSS3 fallbacks). or [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) or [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/)

**Good reads**

[Using CSS3: Older Browsers And Common Considerations](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/03/using-css3-older-browsers-and-common-considerations/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for something like http://selectivizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

FYI

**Google Chrome Frame**

Google Chrome Frame is an open source plug-in that seamlessly brings Google Chrome's open web technologies and speedy JavaScript engine to Internet Explorer. With Google Chrome Frame, you can:

- Start using open web technologies—such as the HTML5 canvas tag—right
  away, even technologies that aren't yet supported in Internet
  Explorer 6, 7, 8, or 9.
- Take advantage of JavaScript performance improvements to make your
  apps faster and more responsive.

http://www.google.com/chromeframe?quickenable=true

Comment: its not a good idea to suggest the client that your website will not work in ie6